# php $variables don't work outside IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, cookies

```
else {
    if ($_COOKIE['HotspotLanguage'] == 'ENG') { 
        $url_lang_code = '?lang=eng'; 
        header('Location: '.$url_captive_portal.$url_lang_code.'');
    } elseif ($_COOKIE['HotspotLanguage'] == 'ALB') { 
        $url_lang_code = '?lang=alb'; 
        header('Location: '.$url_captive_portal.$url_lang_code.''); 
    } elseif ($_COOKIE['HotspotLanguage'] == 'MKD') { 
        $url_lang_code = '?lang=mkd'; 
        header('Location: '.$url_captive_portal.$url_lang_code.'');
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code above, I have defined a variable `$url_lang_code`; however, my variable doesn't work outside the `if` statement.

The URL gets rewritten, that works. But if I use `$url_lang_code`, somewhere outside the if statement, it doesn't work...

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: header takes you to a new page.  Html is state-less, so you will lose your application state every time you go to a new page unless you store the value in a session variable.  Look into PHP sessions if you want to retain the data after a redirect.

Comment: Looks like you've deleted your last question when you found the answer,  try not to do the same now.

Comment: also, you may want to learn how to use switch instead of endless if's http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @PedroLobito I realized I had the cookie name wrong...thats just embarrassing :)

Comment: You could have just update your question instead of deleting it. I had an answer ready to post.... for the record, here it is:  http://pastebin.com/ZT1Bpzye

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the header() method which leaves the current script and loads the page you're requesting.

So you essentially lost that scope, you could store it in a $_SESSION or $_COOKIE var and retrieve it from the other pages you're requesting.

So something like :

```
  else {
    if ($_COOKIE['HotspotLanguage'] == 'ENG') { 
        $_COOKIE['url_lang_code'] = '?lang=eng'; 
        header('Location: '.$url_captive_portal.$url_lang_code);
    } elseif ($_COOKIE['HotspotLanguage'] == 'ALB') { 
        $_COOKIE['url_lang_code'] = '?lang=alb'; 
        header('Location: '.$url_captive_portal.$url_lang_code);  
    } elseif ($_COOKIE['HotspotLanguage'] == 'MKD') { 
        $_COOKIE['url_lang_code'] = '?lang=mkd'; 
        header('Location: '.$url_captive_portal.$url_lang_code);
    }
  }
```